# Network devices manipulation when making a call via Microsoft Teams app

Tags: linux, linux-mint, networkmanager, microsoft-teams, journalctl

I am having an issue with the installation of the Microsoft Teams app on my work notebook Linux mint 19.3 Cinnamon (`5.4.0-54-generic #60~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 17:25:16 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`). There are (among others) docker, virtualbox and barracudavpn installed.

The app can be installed, it can be started, I can write messages with no problem but calls do not work. When I try to call someone then after a 1-3 seconds the call fails with a message "Sorry, we could not connect you".

The app works for my other colleagues (running current Debian and Ubuntu). It even works on my private notebook with Mint 20, but it does not work on my work notebook for some reason.

When I take a look in logs `journalctl -e` I can see these logs (these are logs from the duration of a call attempt):

```
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: br-b37ef822990c: port 2(veth04db846) entered blocking state
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: br-b37ef822990c: port 2(veth04db846) entered disabled state
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: device veth04db846 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805046.7568] manager: (vethc402352): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/319)
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 systemd-udevd[3693]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 systemd-udevd[3693]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethc402352: No such file or directory
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805046.7685] manager: (veth04db846): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/320)
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 systemd-udevd[3695]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 systemd-udevd[3695]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth04db846: No such file or directory
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805046.7940] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethc402352, iface: vethc402352)
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805046.7943] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethc402352, iface: vethc402352): no ifupdown configuration found.
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805046.8098] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth04db846, iface: veth04db846)
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805046.8098] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth04db846, iface: veth04db846): no ifupdown configuration found.
Dec 01 07:44:06 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 containerd[28558]: time="2020-12-01T07:44:06.835581117+01:00" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address="unix:///run/containerd/s/e243515ec8c62dd193787aef6765c555ce85e143ebee92fdd2079
Dec 01 07:44:07 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: eth0: renamed from vethc402352
Dec 01 07:44:07 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth04db846: link becomes ready
Dec 01 07:44:07 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: br-b37ef822990c: port 2(veth04db846) entered blocking state
Dec 01 07:44:07 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: br-b37ef822990c: port 2(veth04db846) entered forwarding state
Dec 01 07:44:07 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805047.1607] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethc402352, iface: vethc402352)
Dec 01 07:44:07 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805047.1614] device (veth04db846): carrier: link connected
Dec 01 07:44:09 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 avahi-daemon[950]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface veth04db846.IPv6 with address fe80::b045:47ff:fe38:c1c1.
Dec 01 07:44:09 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 avahi-daemon[950]: New relevant interface veth04db846.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 01 07:44:09 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 avahi-daemon[950]: Registering new address record for fe80::b045:47ff:fe38:c1c1 on veth04db846.*.
Dec 01 07:44:09 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 containerd[28558]: time="2020-12-01T07:44:09.939175519+01:00" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=7b329ce366c515d93dd6f699f860bf3f33471eda2cec3c2b88d32c40a5ff2e0f
Dec 01 07:44:09 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 dockerd[28596]: time="2020-12-01T07:44:09.949397888+01:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Dec 01 07:44:09 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: br-b37ef822990c: port 2(veth04db846) entered disabled state
Dec 01 07:44:09 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: vethc402352: renamed from eth0
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805050.0295] manager: (vethc402352): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/321)
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 systemd-udevd[3923]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 avahi-daemon[950]: Interface veth04db846.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 avahi-daemon[950]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface veth04db846.IPv6 with address fe80::b045:47ff:fe38:c1c1.
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: br-b37ef822990c: port 2(veth04db846) entered disabled state
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: device veth04db846 left promiscuous mode
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 kernel: br-b37ef822990c: port 2(veth04db846) entered disabled state
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 avahi-daemon[950]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::b045:47ff:fe38:c1c1 on veth04db846.
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805050.0854] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethc402352, iface: vethc402352)
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805050.0855] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethc402352, iface: vethc402352): no ifupdown configuration found.
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805050.0857] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethc402352, iface: vethc402352)
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805050.0878] device (veth04db846): released from master device br-b37ef822990c
Dec 01 07:44:10 etomek-HP-EliteBook-850-G3 NetworkManager[918]: <info>  [1606805050.0983] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth04db846, iface: veth04db846)
```

Can anyone explain what is happening there? What can trigger these changes? On my colleagues's notebooks and on my private notebook there are no logs when trying to make a test call. This brings me to the idea that the problem is this manipulation with network devices. Right now my workaround is to use the webapp in browser... it works but does not have all the features of a desktop app (e.g. custom background, seeing multiple call attendants video simultaneously,...)

Please can someone take a look at this log and give me some hint what to check next?

Comment: Can anyone at least give me a hint what can cause this network devices manipulation when making a call via the MS Teams app?